# How to properly read multiple zlib streams from one base stream (Git Packfile) in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, zlib, inflate, nodejs-stream

I'm creating a NodeJS module to interact with git repositories and I'm trying to read Packfiles coming from public git hostings like GitHub.
The problem is, Packfiles are made of many zlib streams but I can't figure out how to:

- inflate (uncompress) the first zlib stream
- do something with it
- inflate the next zlib stream
- etc.

Here is the minimal example:

```
// main.js
const zlib = require('zlib')
const Readable = require('stream').Readable;

function createZlibStream(count = 1) {
  const s = new Readable();
  s._read = () => {};
  for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    s.push(zlib.deflateSync("stream" + i));
  }
  s.push(null);

  return s;
}

function readZlibStream(stream) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var data = "",
      zlibStream = zlib.createInflate();

    stream
      .pipe(zlibStream)
      .on("data", chunk => {
        data += chunk;
      })
      .on("end", () => {
        stream.unpipe(zlibStream)
        resolve(data);
      })
  });
}

var stream = createZlibStream(1)

readZlibStream(stream)
 .then(console.log)
 .catch(console.error)
```

That's cool to read 1 stream, but if you generate two streams, by replacing:

```
var stream = createZlibStream(1)

readZlibStream(stream)
 .then(console.log)
 .catch(console.error)
```

with:

```
var stream = createZlibStream(2)

readZlibStream(stream)
 .then((data) => {
  console.log(data)
  readZlibStream(stream)
   .then(console.log)
   .catch(console.error)
 })
 .catch(console.error)
```

You'll get that output:

```
user@hostname:~/zlib-error$ node main.js
stream0
events.js:174
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: unexpected end of file
    at Zlib.zlibOnError [as onerror] (zlib.js:162:17)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at Zlib.zlibOnError [as onerror] (zlib.js:165:8)
```